# Graph API won't retrieve security groups

Tags: python, permissions, microsoft-graph-api, network-security-groups

I'm trying to build a simple API call that retrieves all groups in my organization.
When I do this call: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups, the response is successful, but it won't bring all groups, there are no security groups in that list.

The odd thing is, if i do the call specifying the id of a given security group https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{id}, it will bring me the data for that group.

I've been investigating and can't find why is this, I'm starting to think you can't pull security groups in a list, and you can only do it calling it one by one.

I have Group.Read.All permission granted for the user I'm authenticating with.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when calling `/v1.0/users/user-id/memberOf`. I'm an admin in my AD so I get the security groups in the result, but when a normal user does the same query, it will return all groups, except security groups. If you use an Application Token instead of a Delegated Token, it should work.